# Devexpress controls. ASPxScheduler and ASPxCalendar

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have a page with ASPxSheduler,where i can add recurring appointments.In another page I have ASPxCalendar,where I Want to show all the appointments in the scheduler. I have problem with showing recurring appointments in this calendar.Help,please.

Comment: RecurrenceInfo is saved in db as a string. I tried to get it from db, save it as XML,and read the information stored in it. But it is will be diffucult to check all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RWA](http://demos.devexpress.com/RWA/WebmailClient/Calendar.aspx) demo.

It illustrates how to filter ASPxScheduler via ASPxCalendar selection.

Comment: The full source code is available on any machine where DXperience is installed: C:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress 2011.2 Demos\

Answer (score 0):

You can filter ASPxScheduler via ASPxDateNavigator. its look like ASPxCalendar, but it different control, which you can bind to ASPxScheduler using MasterControlID property